# AWS boto - stop servers in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, boto

So here is my little piece of code that is supposed to stop multiple servers in threads:

```
for x in range(amount):
    server_id = str(servers[x][4])
    t = threading.Thread(target=stop_server, args=(server_id))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Now, the issue is that server_id is not properly passed to the target function that in this case is "stop_server". The error I am getting is:

```
Invalid id: "i"
```

Knowing that AWS ids are 10 characters, such as "i-abcd1234" I checked what is in "server_id" just before I passed it into "t" and I saw full ID.

The question is why is it getting truncated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - a coma was missing after "server_id" in args....